# How to debug a Singer Tap using VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, meltano, singer-io

In creating new Singer Taps using the [Meltano SDK](https://sdk.meltano.com), it's not always clear how to setup testing in VS Code.

What's the best way to get the VS Code test features working?

Comment: Inspired by this [Meltano Slack](https://meltano.com/slack) thread: https://meltano.slack.com/archives/C01TCRBBJD7/p1649701024240939

Answer (score 3):

### First Method: Unit testing with VS Code "Tests" pane

*This method makes unit tests (`pytest` tests) easy to run in the VS Code "Tests" pane.*

Prereqs:

- Python is installed on your machine.
- The Python VS Code extension is installed.
- You've run `poetry install` at least once.
- You've set the Python interpreter to the Poetry environment via: "Command Palette" > "Python: Select Interpreter" and then select the matching Poetry environment.

Once the above are complete, the "tests" pane should populate with the list of unit tests and you'll have an option in the VS Code GUI to "Run" or "Debug" each test.

### Second Method: Integration test by actually invoking the tap

*This method actually runs your tap and sends the output to `target-json` or a similar sample target.*

Prereqs:

- Add a `main` to the bottom of your `tap.py` to make it invocable:

  ```
  if __name__ == "__main__":
    TapGoogleAnalytics.cli()
  ```
- Install `target-jsonl` via `pipx install target-jsonl` or similar.

Replace `tap_foobar` with the actual name of your tap's library and then paste this into VS Code's `launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/tap_foobar/tap.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": ["--config", ".secrets/config.json", "|", "target-jsonl"],
            "env": { "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}"}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks to Stéphane Burwash and Pat Nadolny for the sample code, noted the Slack thread mentioned above in Question comments.

Comment: Another simple thing I can suggest is Directly passing config, state to TapGoogleAnalytics and probably call sync_all on it? If one don't want to modify debug config if they are working on multiple taps, targets or other code